# Largest component and number of components of random mappings with bounded in-degree

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-graphs, random-functions

Let $S$ be a finite set of size $n$ and consider all functions $f$ from $S$ to itself, such that the preimage $f^{-1} (k)$ obeys  $0 \leq |f^{-1} (k)| \leq m$.

Let $F$ be chosen uniformly at random from the set of all such functions. We may look at $F$ as a random directed graph with edges $(x, F(x))$.

- Is anything known about the size of the largest connected component of $F$?
- Is anything known about the expected number of connected components of $F$?

I am especially interested in asymptotics.

Comment: You can find some results here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102723961